# Python: Calculate percentage of coordinates in relation to surrounding coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I am having a dictionary with 3D tuple coordinates as keys and string scores as values. Now I want to get a new list/dict/array of coordinates which should be the percent value of the coordinate and all surrounding coordinates in a 12x12x12 box. Is there a faster way than to grab the coordinates from a dictionary like in my first approach? (sparse1 is the dictionary with the original coordinates). In the code sparse1 is only an extraction of coordinates from one Tube (because i dont know how to add more characters here :( ):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools


sparse1 = {(32.0, 291.0, 3.0): ['-2'], (16.0, 299.0, 23.0): ['-2'], (22.0, 303.0, 24.0): ['2'], (30.0, 296.0, 16.0): ['1'], (27.0, 305.0, 10.0): ['1'], (21.0, 290.0, 16.0): ['2'], (27.0, 295.0, 15.0): ['-2'], (36.0, 293.0, -2.0): ['2'], (37.0, 292.0, 5.0): ['2'], (24.0, 312.0, 18.0): ['2'], (21.0, 307.0, 25.0): ['-2'], (20.0, 304.0, 17.0): ['1'], (26.0, 291.0, 18.0): ['-2'], (17.0, 308.0, 10.0): ['2'], (32.0, 313.0, 11.0): ['2'], (32.0, 303.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 294.0, 10.0): ['2'], (22.0, 299.0, 19.0): ['2'], (24.0, 293.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (20.0, 303.0, 20.0): ['2'], (20.0, 293.0, 3.0): ['2'], (19.0, 298.0, 28.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 297.0, -1.0): ['2'], (31.0, 310.0, 11.0): ['-2'], (22.0, 300.0, 26.0): ['2'], (21.0, 311.0, 14.0): ['2'], (35.0, 306.0, 13.0): ['2'], (15.0, 308.0, 14.0): ['2'], (27.0, 296.0, 21.0): ['2'], (28.0, 289.0, 0.0): ['2'], (18.0, 309.0, 9.0): ['2'], (31.0, 297.0, 1.0): ['2'], (23.0, 312.0, 15.0): ['2'], (26.0, 295.0, 13.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 302.0, 9.0): ['1'], (16.0, 301.0, 26.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 307.0, 17.0): ['2'], (24.0, 299.0, 18.0): ['2'], (32.0, 290.0, -3.0): ['2'], (12.0, 301.0, 27.0): ['2'], (33.0, 311.0, 11.0): ['1'], (20.0, 291.0, 19.0): ['2'], (26.0, 310.0, 12.0): ['2'], (21.0, 305.0, 6.0): ['1'], (36.0, 289.0, 12.0): ['2'], (23.0, 290.0, 1.0): ['2'], (20.0, 306.0, 30.0): ['2'], (30.0, 308.0, 2.0): ['1'], (15.0, 296.0, 25.0): ['-2'], (28.0, 293.0, 11.0): ['-2'], (31.0, 301.0, 6.0): ['2'], (17.0, 298.0, 29.0): ['1'], (32.0, 289.0, 1.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 292.0, 17.0): ['-2'], (23.0, 307.0, 24.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 292.0, 22.0): ['1'], (27.0, 293.0, 9.0): ['2'], (26.0, 304.0, 0.0): ['2'], (20.0, 295.0, 14.0): ['2'], (25.0, 309.0, 24.0): ['2'], (24.0, 310.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 309.0, 27.0): ['1'], (14.0, 306.0, 23.0): ['-2'], (23.0, 294.0, 12.0): ['2'], (20.0, 310.0, 19.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 309.0, 12.0): ['-2'], (33.0, 302.0, 12.0): ['2'], (26.0, 293.0, 20.0): ['1'], (30.0, 294.0, 19.0): ['2'], (25.0, 288.0, 12.0): ['2'], (29.0, 305.0, 14.0): ['2'], (24.0, 291.0, 4.0): ['2'], (33.0, 309.0, 4.0): ['2'], (28.0, 294.0, -1.0): ['-2'], (20.0, 301.0, 22.0): ['2'], (32.0, 310.0, 12.0): ['-2'], (19.0, 296.0, 30.0): ['2'], (25.0, 305.0, 21.0): ['2'], (22.0, 292.0, 4.0): ['2'], (30.0, 307.0, 1.0): ['1'], (34.0, 303.0, 7.0): ['1'], (28.0, 295.0, 6.0): ['2'], (18.0, 311.0, 11.0): ['2'], (31.0, 303.0, 3.0): ['1'], (30.0, 296.0, 11.0): ['1'], (16.0, 299.0, 28.0): ['-2'], (35.0, 289.0, 10.0): ['-2'], (13.0, 304.0, 29.0): ['2'], (29.0, 309.0, 19.0): ['2'], (25.0, 291.0, -1.0): ['2'], (24.0, 297.0, 16.0): ['1'], (27.0, 295.0, 6.0): ['2'], (33.0, 305.0, 9.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 296.0, 14.0): ['1'], (29.0, 295.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (22.0, 298.0, 26.0): ['1'], (18.0, 293.0, 19.0): ['2'], (29.0, 296.0, 13.0): ['1'], (18.0, 305.0, 27.0): ['-2'], (19.0, 309.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (31.0, 291.0, 4.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 294.0, 19.0): ['-2'], (22.0, 299.0, 28.0): ['2'], (24.0, 293.0, 11.0): ['2'], (21.0, 294.0, 20.0): ['-2'], (27.0, 291.0, 11.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 306.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (19.0, 298.0, 21.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 294.0, 0.0): ['-2'], (24.0, 308.0, 22.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 305.0, 8.0): ['-2'], (14.0, 300.0, 21.0): ['2'], (37.0, 293.0, -1.0): ['2'], (23.0, 292.0, 14.0): ['1'], (29.0, 290.0, 17.0): ['2'], (20.0, 308.0, 13.0): ['-2'], (33.0, 296.0, 10.0): ['2'], (26.0, 295.0, 22.0): ['2'], (30.0, 306.0, 7.0): ['-2'], (17.0, 304.0, 14.0): ['2'], (30.0, 302.0, 0.0): ['2'], (25.0, 290.0, 14.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 307.0, 8.0): ['-2'], (31.0, 308.0, 3.0): ['1'], (28.0, 293.0, 8.0): ['2'], (37.0, 287.0, 5.0): ['2'], (20.0, 291.0, 24.0): ['2'], (35.0, 294.0, 7.0): ['2'], (32.0, 308.0, 10.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 293.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (19.0, 294.0, 16.0): ['2'], (25.0, 307.0, 11.0): ['-2'], (22.0, 294.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 305.0, 9.0): ['-2'], (27.0, 310.0, 20.0): ['2'], (18.0, 303.0, 14.0): ['2'], (28.0, 293.0, 4.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 296.0, -2.0): ['2'], (23.0, 307.0, 19.0): ['-2'], (28.0, 294.0, 10.0): ['1'], (27.0, 293.0, 0.0): ['-2'], (33.0, 307.0, 7.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 304.0, 11.0): ['1'], (20.0, 295.0, 23.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 309.0, 3.0): ['2'], (36.0, 293.0, 8.0): ['2'], (23.0, 294.0, 5.0): ['1'], (29.0, 298.0, 15.0): ['2'], (28.0, 291.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (15.0, 300.0, 29.0): ['1'], (19.0, 307.0, 18.0): ['-2'], (31.0, 289.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 297.0, -2.0): ['2'], (35.0, 293.0, 4.0): ['1'], (29.0, 305.0, 1.0): ['1'], (25.0, 293.0, -3.0): ['2'], (24.0, 291.0, 13.0): ['1'], (28.0, 306.0, 9.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 308.0, 4.0): ['1'], (17.0, 295.0, 24.0): ['-2'], (32.0, 310.0, 7.0): ['2'], (19.0, 296.0, 23.0): ['-2'], (16.0, 298.0, 20.0): ['2'], (24.0, 306.0, 20.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 307.0, 10.0): ['-2'], (23.0, 298.0, 0.0): ['1'], (29.0, 302.0, 2.0): ['1'], (30.0, 305.0, 3.0): ['-2'], (31.0, 293.0, 7.0): ['1'], (17.0, 306.0, 12.0): ['2'], (30.0, 296.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (32.0, 297.0, 0.0): ['2'], (24.0, 298.0, -1.0): ['1'], (35.0, 289.0, 1.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 309.0, 10.0): ['-2'], (12.0, 307.0, 26.0): ['2'], (28.0, 310.0, 18.0): ['1'], (26.0, 294.0, -3.0): ['2'], (33.0, 295.0, -2.0): ['2'], (26.0, 296.0, 1.0): ['-2'], (32.0, 306.0, 8.0): ['-2'], (19.0, 292.0, 18.0): ['2'], (25.0, 301.0, 9.0): ['2'], (22.0, 298.0, 17.0): ['1'], (21.0, 307.0, 15.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 295.0, 25.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 296.0, 18.0): ['2'], (15.0, 302.0, 20.0): ['2'], (21.0, 310.0, 20.0): ['-2'], (31.0, 291.0, 15.0): ['-2'], (17.0, 308.0, 24.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 292.0, 7.0): ['1'], (24.0, 297.0, 26.0): ['2'], (23.0, 305.0, 21.0): ['-2'], (13.0, 308.0, 25.0): ['1'], (27.0, 291.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (27.0, 297.0, 15.0): ['2'], (26.0, 306.0, 13.0): ['2'], (20.0, 293.0, 21.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 294.0, 23.0): ['2'], (16.0, 294.0, 25.0): ['1'], (35.0, 286.0, 5.0): ['1'], (38.0, 292.0, 3.0): ['2'], (19.0, 305.0, 12.0): ['-2'], (31.0, 295.0, 0.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 312.0, 23.0): ['2'], (35.0, 291.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (16.0, 307.0, 15.0): ['1'], (29.0, 307.0, 7.0): ['-2'], (24.0, 289.0, 15.0): ['2'], (15.0, 307.0, 30.0): ['2'], (31.0, 286.0, 8.0): ['1'], (19.0, 294.0, 25.0): ['1'], (25.0, 307.0, 2.0): ['1'], (22.0, 294.0, 25.0): ['1'], (24.0, 304.0, 10.0): ['-2'], (27.0, 310.0, 13.0): ['1'], (23.0, 296.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (20.0, 306.0, 8.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 308.0, 24.0): ['-2'], (22.0, 305.0, 18.0): ['1'], (34.0, 306.0, 3.0): ['2'], (23.0, 307.0, 10.0): ['-2'], (34.0, 288.0, 11.0): ['-2'], (12.0, 305.0, 24.0): ['2'], (18.0, 296.0, 23.0): ['-2'], (33.0, 307.0, 14.0): ['2'], (20.0, 295.0, 28.0): ['2'], (32.0, 304.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 309.0, 10.0): ['1'], (22.0, 290.0, 14.0): ['2'], (21.0, 309.0, 13.0): ['-2'], (27.0, 306.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 303.0, 6.0): ['2'], (23.0, 294.0, 18.0): ['-2'], (15.0, 300.0, 22.0): ['-2'], (19.0, 307.0, 29.0): ['1'], (31.0, 289.0, 9.0): ['-2'], (17.0, 310.0, 26.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 294.0, 1.0): ['-2'], (23.0, 311.0, 23.0): ['2'], (13.0, 310.0, 27.0): ['2'], (28.0, 306.0, 0.0): ['1'], (27.0, 289.0, 12.0): ['1'], (26.0, 308.0, 15.0): ['-2'], (36.0, 286.0, 5.0): ['2'], (26.0, 302.0, 4.0): ['1'], (25.0, 305.0, 7.0): ['-2'], (22.0, 292.0, 22.0): ['1'], (29.0, 302.0, 11.0): ['2'], (19.0, 303.0, 14.0): ['2'], (22.0, 311.0, 13.0): ['2'], (28.0, 288.0, 6.0): ['2'], (30.0, 290.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (16.0, 305.0, 13.0): ['2'], (29.0, 309.0, 5.0): ['1'], (27.0, 295.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (28.0, 310.0, 13.0): ['-2'], (18.0, 294.0, 28.0): ['2'], (27.0, 301.0, 1.0): ['2'], (32.0, 306.0, 3.0): ['1'], (34.0, 290.0, -3.0): ['2'], (20.0, 305.0, 28.0): ['1'], (24.0, 302.0, 8.0): ['1'], (27.0, 308.0, 15.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 295.0, 16.0): ['1'], (23.0, 302.0, 4.0): ['2'], (20.0, 304.0, 14.0): ['-2'], (20.0, 302.0, 11.0): ['2'], (20.0, 292.0, 24.0): ['2'], (38.0, 290.0, 2.0): ['1'], (22.0, 307.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (17.0, 308.0, 17.0): ['1'], (30.0, 292.0, 14.0): ['-2'], (18.0, 302.0, 29.0): ['1'], (16.0, 311.0, 25.0): ['1'], (14.0, 309.0, 24.0): ['-2'], (13.0, 308.0, 22.0): ['1'], (34.0, 290.0, 13.0): ['1'], (19.0, 308.0, 20.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 300.0, 5.0): ['2'], (26.0, 294.0, 14.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 294.0, 3.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 297.0, 13.0): ['2'], (24.0, 308.0, 4.0): ['1'], (21.0, 311.0, 19.0): ['1'], (27.0, 304.0, 18.0): ['2'], (23.0, 292.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (20.0, 308.0, 27.0): ['-2'], (18.0, 309.0, 20.0): ['1'], (31.0, 295.0, 11.0): ['-2'], (17.0, 304.0, 28.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 288.0, 3.0): ['-2'], (23.0, 309.0, 25.0): ['1'], (14.0, 305.0, 23.0): ['1'], (30.0, 293.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (19.0, 311.0, 22.0): ['1'], (28.0, 304.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (31.0, 286.0, 1.0): ['1'], (26.0, 310.0, 17.0): ['-2'], (35.0, 294.0, 2.0): ['1'], (29.0, 293.0, 7.0): ['2'], (25.0, 307.0, 25.0): ['2'], (22.0, 294.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (13.0, 297.0, 28.0): ['2'], (22.0, 296.0, 1.0): ['-2'], (24.0, 304.0, 1.0): ['2'], (21.0, 299.0, 24.0): ['-2'], (20.0, 296.0, 0.0): ['2'], (19.0, 311.0, 11.0): ['2'], (15.0, 294.0, 23.0): ['2'], (22.0, 305.0, 11.0): ['-2'], (33.0, 286.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 311.0, 11.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 289.0, 12.0): ['-2'], (34.0, 288.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (28.0, 308.0, 3.0): ['-2'], (18.0, 296.0, 30.0): ['2'], (27.0, 299.0, 3.0): ['2'], (33.0, 293.0, 10.0): ['-2'], (17.0, 301.0, 22.0): ['-2'], (32.0, 304.0, 13.0): ['1'], (25.0, 303.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (16.0, 297.0, 21.0): ['2'], (22.0, 290.0, 21.0): ['2'], (27.0, 306.0, 9.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 303.0, 13.0): ['1'], (36.0, 307.0, 9.0): ['2'], (20.0, 310.0, 12.0): ['1'], (38.0, 288.0, -1.0): ['2'], (34.0, 287.0, 5.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 296.0, 15.0): ['1'], (17.0, 310.0, 19.0): ['2'], (30.0, 294.0, 8.0): ['2'], (21.0, 304.0, 22.0): ['1'], (16.0, 309.0, 27.0): ['-2'], (14.0, 311.0, 26.0): ['2'], (35.0, 305.0, 12.0): ['2'], (34.0, 292.0, 15.0): ['2'], (27.0, 289.0, 19.0): ['2'], (30.0, 287.0, 0.0): ['2'], (25.0, 305.0, 14.0): ['1'], (16.0, 298.0, 25.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 299.0, 3.0): ['2'], (22.0, 302.0, 10.0): ['1'], (24.0, 306.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 297.0, 17.0): ['1'], (21.0, 291.0, 2.0): ['2'], (20.0, 298.0, 25.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 305.0, 20.0): ['2'], (18.0, 311.0, 22.0): ['1'], (30.0, 305.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (17.0, 306.0, 30.0): ['2'], (24.0, 296.0, 21.0): ['-2'], (32.0, 287.0, 1.0): ['-2'], (14.0, 307.0, 21.0): ['1'], (28.0, 310.0, 4.0): ['2'], (31.0, 284.0, 3.0): ['2'], (26.0, 296.0, 19.0): ['1'], (26.0, 290.0, 0.0): ['2'], (13.0, 299.0, 26.0): ['1'], (24.0, 302.0, 3.0): ['2'], (27.0, 308.0, 0.0): ['2'], (21.0, 301.0, 26.0): ['2'], (23.0, 302.0, 13.0): ['2'], (20.0, 292.0, 15.0): ['2'], (30.0, 310.0, 4.0): ['2'], (19.0, 309.0, 13.0): ['-2'], (22.0, 307.0, 9.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 313.0, 9.0): ['2'], (29.0, 291.0, 10.0): ['-2'], (34.0, 290.0, 4.0): ['-2'], (27.0, 291.0, 20.0): ['2'], (18.0, 298.0, 24.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 296.0, -3.0): ['2'], (33.0, 295.0, 12.0): ['1'], (17.0, 303.0, 16.0): ['2'], (26.0, 294.0, 5.0): ['1'], (25.0, 297.0, 4.0): ['1'], (22.0, 300.0, 23.0): ['1'], (22.0, 309.0, 28.0): ['2'], (27.0, 304.0, 11.0): ['2'], (20.0, 308.0, 18.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 311.0, 14.0): ['1'], (19.0, 305.0, 26.0): ['-2'], (17.0, 304.0, 21.0): ['2'], (30.0, 288.0, 10.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 306.0, 20.0): ['-2'], (16.0, 307.0, 29.0): ['1'], (14.0, 305.0, 28.0): ['1'], (34.0, 294.0, 1.0): ['-2'], (32.0, 291.0, -2.0): ['1'], (25.0, 307.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 293.0, 1.0): ['-2'], (24.0, 304.0, 24.0): ['2'], (21.0, 299.0, 23.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 293.0, 0.0): ['2'], (26.0, 307.0, 22.0): ['2'], (33.0, 286.0, 11.0): ['1'], (32.0, 285.0, 3.0): ['1'], (29.0, 289.0, 7.0): ['1'], (28.0, 308.0, 10.0): ['-2'], (28.0, 290.0, 15.0): ['-2'], (31.0, 296.0, 12.0): ['1'], (32.0, 290.0, -2.0): ['1'], (26.0, 298.0, 21.0): ['2'], (17.0, 301.0, 25.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 292.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (32.0, 294.0, 5.0): ['1'], (29.0, 286.0, 6.0): ['2'], (29.0, 297.0, 0.0): ['1'], (13.0, 301.0, 24.0): ['1'], (27.0, 306.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 303.0, 20.0): ['2'], (27.0, 312.0, 17.0): ['2'], (19.0, 307.0, 15.0): ['-2'], (31.0, 309.0, 9.0): ['-2'], (20.0, 307.0, 23.0): ['-2'], (34.0, 292.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (32.0, 301.0, 4.0): ['2'], (34.0, 302.0, 11.0): ['2'], (18.0, 300.0, 26.0): ['-2'], (33.0, 289.0, 14.0): ['1'], (29.0, 296.0, 14.0): ['-2'], (24.0, 296.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (19.0, 303.0, 24.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 308.0, 21.0): ['1'], (31.0, 307.0, 13.0): ['-2'], (17.0, 306.0, 23.0): ['-2'], (23.0, 292.0, -1.0): ['1'], (15.0, 302.0, 24.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 308.0, 5.0): ['-2'], (14.0, 307.0, 30.0): ['2'], (34.0, 296.0, 3.0): ['2'], (18.0, 304.0, 15.0): ['1'], (24.0, 293.0, -2.0): ['1'], (26.0, 290.0, 15.0): ['-2'], (35.0, 292.0, 5.0): ['-2'], (34.0, 305.0, 9.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 301.0, 21.0): ['2'], (20.0, 302.0, 29.0): ['2'], (31.0, 291.0, -1.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 309.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 291.0, 1.0): ['-2'], (28.0, 292.0, 4.0): ['-2'], (15.0, 309.0, 27.0): ['-2'], (24.0, 292.0, -1.0): ['1'], (28.0, 288.0, 9.0): ['2'], (31.0, 302.0, 10.0): ['1'], (35.0, 295.0, 1.0): ['2'], (20.0, 306.0, 27.0): ['-2'], (32.0, 292.0, 3.0): ['-2'], (16.0, 300.0, 23.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 291.0, 4.0): ['2'], (27.0, 304.0, 4.0): ['-2'], (27.0, 294.0, 15.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 297.0, 3.0): ['2'], (19.0, 305.0, 17.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 306.0, 1.0): ['1'], (37.0, 291.0, 5.0): ['1'], (21.0, 306.0, 29.0): ['2'], (22.0, 292.0, -1.0): ['2'], (29.0, 295.0, 6.0): ['2'], (34.0, 294.0, 8.0): ['1'], (25.0, 293.0, 18.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 288.0, 16.0): ['2'], (22.0, 296.0, 19.0): ['-2'], (24.0, 294.0, 0.0): ['-2'], (20.0, 296.0, 22.0): ['-2'], (20.0, 294.0, 3.0): ['2'], (19.0, 301.0, 30.0): ['2'], (25.0, 310.0, 23.0): ['2'], (29.0, 298.0, -1.0): ['2'], (31.0, 305.0, 11.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 310.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (36.0, 292.0, 10.0): ['1'], (28.0, 290.0, 6.0): ['2'], (18.0, 306.0, 9.0): ['-2'], (31.0, 296.0, 5.0): ['2'], (26.0, 292.0, 13.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 303.0, 13.0): ['2'], (16.0, 302.0, 24.0): ['-2'], (34.0, 307.0, 11.0): ['1'], (21.0, 303.0, 27.0): ['2'], (12.0, 302.0, 27.0): ['2'], (23.0, 300.0, 24.0): ['2'], (26.0, 311.0, 18.0): ['1'], (25.0, 312.0, 15.0): ['2'], (37.0, 289.0, 10.0): ['2'], (21.0, 304.0, 4.0): ['2'], (36.0, 290.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 293.0, 3.0): ['-2'], (28.0, 312.0, 14.0): ['2'], (15.0, 299.0, 25.0): ['-2'], (28.0, 294.0, 11.0): ['1'], (17.0, 297.0, 29.0): ['1'], (32.0, 290.0, 1.0): ['-2'], (23.0, 306.0, 21.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 299.0, 17.0): ['2'], (16.0, 298.0, 21.0): ['1'], (21.0, 291.0, 16.0): ['2'], (27.0, 292.0, 13.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 305.0, 2.0): ['-2'], (37.0, 293.0, 7.0): ['2'], (24.0, 311.0, 18.0): ['1'], (34.0, 311.0, 13.0): ['2'], (21.0, 308.0, 27.0): ['1'], (28.0, 288.0, 4.0): ['2'], (23.0, 289.0, 14.0): ['2'], (29.0, 297.0, 4.0): ['2'], (34.0, 296.0, 10.0): ['2'], (17.0, 309.0, 14.0): ['1'], (30.0, 301.0, 4.0): ['1'], (25.0, 295.0, 14.0): ['-2'], (29.0, 304.0, 12.0): ['1'], (28.0, 307.0, 20.0): ['2'], (33.0, 308.0, 6.0): ['1'], (21.0, 310.0, 26.0): ['1'], (32.0, 311.0, 14.0): ['2'], (19.0, 299.0, 28.0): ['-2'], (25.0, 304.0, 17.0): ['1'], (31.0, 311.0, 9.0): ['1'], (21.0, 296.0, 14.0): ['2'], (28.0, 288.0, 0.0): ['2'], (18.0, 308.0, 11.0): ['1'], (31.0, 302.0, 3.0): ['1'], (30.0, 297.0, 11.0): ['2'], (25.0, 297.0, 22.0): ['2'], (16.0, 300.0, 30.0): ['2'], (13.0, 303.0, 29.0): ['2'], (29.0, 308.0, 19.0): ['2'], (34.0, 309.0, 13.0): ['2'], (29.0, 300.0, 6.0): ['2'], (27.0, 294.0, 4.0): ['-2'], (30.0, 311.0, 9.0): ['-2'], (26.0, 297.0, 12.0): ['2'], (21.0, 306.0, 6.0): ['1'], (36.0, 288.0, 4.0): ['1'], (23.0, 291.0, 3.0): ['2'], (29.0, 295.0, 13.0): ['-2'], (18.0, 302.0, 27.0): ['-2'], (28.0, 292.0, 5.0): ['1'], (31.0, 290.0, 6.0): ['-2'], (22.0, 309.0, 17.0): ['-2'], (32.0, 288.0, 15.0): ['2'], (35.0, 294.0, 0.0): ['1'], (23.0, 304.0, 24.0): ['2'], (22.0, 296.0, 26.0): ['1'], (24.0, 294.0, 11.0): ['2'], (21.0, 293.0, 18.0): ['-2'], (27.0, 290.0, 11.0): ['1'], (26.0, 307.0, 0.0): ['2'], (28.0, 291.0, -1.0): ['1'], (19.0, 301.0, 21.0): ['2'], (25.0, 310.0, 24.0): ['2'], (24.0, 299.0, 20.0): ['2'], (24.0, 309.0, 16.0): ['-2'], (21.0, 310.0, 25.0): ['1']}

    sparse2 = sparse1.copy()
    subCubes = tuple(np.arange(-6,7))          
    cube = np.array(list(itertools.product(subCubes, subCubes, subCubes)))
    for i in cube:
       for d in sparse1:
           coor = float(sparse1.get(d)[0])
           if coor > 0 :
               value=0#float(sparse1.get(tuple(d))[0])
               for c in cube:
                   value = value + max(0,float(sparse1.get(tuple(d+c),"0")[0]))               
               procentValue = coor/float(value)
               sparse2[d] = [str(procentValue)]   
           else:
               sparse2[d] = [str(0.0)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your solution is clever, it adds unnecessary processing due to treating each key in `sparse1` as being completely unrelated to every other key except through the makeshift lookup table `cube`.  If you preprocess `sparse1` to calculate the [Chebyshev distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) between the geometric values described by the keys, you can use that to find the neighboring values and sum them.  This eliminates the loop over `cube` array, replacing it with a more efficient index and sum.

This is an attempt to replicate your code using [`radius_neighbors_graph`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.radius_neighbors_graph.html) from sklearn.neighbors:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import radius_neighbors_graph

sparse1 = ...

X = np.array([list(k) for k in sparse1.keys()])
N = radius_neighbors_graph(X, radius=6, metric='chebyshev').astype(bool)

Y = np.array([max(0, float(v[0])) for v in sparse1.values()])
sparse2 = {}
for x, y, n in zip(X, Y, N):
    t = tuple(x)
    if sparse1[t][0][0] == '-':  # check the string value rather than converting
        sparse2[t] = sparse1[t]
    else:
        v = Y[np.squeeze(n.toarray())].sum()  # eliminates looping over cube
        v += y  # radius_neighbors_graph does not consider a point a neighbor of itself
        v += y  # potential bug in OP?  See below.
        if v <= 0:
            p = 1.
        else:
            p = y / v
        sparse2[t] = [str(p)]
```

There are a few things here of note:

1. I convert the tuple keys into the numpy array `X`, which costs memory.
2. I perform the neighbor calculations up front and store them, which costs memory (though `N` is sparse, so not too much).
3. I convert the values of the map into floats once and store them in `Y`, which also costs memory, but saves having to repeatedly perform the conversions.
4. The line marked as a potential bug replicates a feature of your algorithm: `value=float(sparse1.get(tuple(d))[0])` replicates the adding the value from `(0,0,0)` when looping over `cube`, so the OP adds this value twice.

Running some simple benchmarks, this version of the algorithm runs about 70 times faster, give or take.  My guess is most of that comes from the removal of the loop over `cube`.

Comment: Ok, this seems very fast. Thank you a lot!!!!!.  I made a test, but i think there are some things missing. So my code produced a dictionary sparse2 that has no negative values and only percentage values in the output. In the new approach there are negative values in the output. And there are some things i do not understand. Maybe you could explain them :) So the expression "for x,y,n in zip(X,Y,N)" is seperately looping x in X, y in Y and n in N? And what exactly does the Chebyshev distances do. I tried to understand the wiki article but dont understand it yet.

Comment: It calculates the maximum difference between to points, but what happens then? And what is squeeze exactly doing. I read it eliminates unneeded dimension?, what exactly means that?

Best regard!

Comment: @Varlor, are you sure it is true that there are no negative values in the map?  You copy `sparse1` into `sparse2`, then have the conditional `if float(sparse1.get(d)[0]) >= 0 :` in the `for` loop over `sparse1`.  Any negative values that were in `sparse1` will be unmodified by the loop, meaning `sparse2` will still contain them.

Comment: @Varlor, your understanding of `zip` is correct.  `zip` a python built-in function that iterates over all iterables listed in its arguments together until it reaches the end of the shortest iterable.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: @Varlor, the Chebyshev is the maximum separation between two points along any single dimension.  All points with a Chebyshev distance of 6 from a given point defines a hypercube of side length 12 with the point at the center of that cube, which is exactly what adding each element of `cube` to a given point attempts to emulate.

Comment: Yes you are right, i made a mistake in my code, so now the bug is fixed and the else condition should process every negative number to 0. Is it also possible to scale then the existing numbers in sparse2 between 1 and 100? Best regards!

Comment: @Varlor, the call to `radius_neighbor_graph` returns a matrix `N` where the element `N[i,j]` is either `1` if points `X[i]` and `X[j]` are within a Chebyshev distance of 6 from each other, or `0` if they are not (or if `i==j`).  I convert these to Boolean values so that they can be used as indices.  When iterating over `N`, `n.toarray()` is actually a matrix of dimension `(len(Y),1)`.  It needs to have that singleton dimension dropped before it can be used as in index array for `Y`.  That is what `squeeze` does.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146330/discussion-between-paste-and-varlor).